# Get ICompilationUnit/ITypeRoot from standalone java file for Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am hacking an Eclipse Plugin that is working perfectly for Java files in Java projects. I want to make it work for Java files in any kind of project.

This plugin processes each Java file as a `ICompilationUnit`.
However, in my approach I can only get an instance of `IFile`.

**How can I create a `ICompilationUnit` from this `IFile` object?**

As alternative a `ITypeRoot` might also work. I've seen this being created directly from the editor using the following:

```
IJavaElement input= JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement(editorInput);
        if (input instanceof ITypeRoot) {
            return (ITypeRoot) input;
        }
```

This approach works even with non Java projects (java files from generic projects/directories that are opened in the editor), which makes me believe that something similar can be achieved for files directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JavaCore.create(IFile)` will return an `ICompilationUnit` if that is appropriate for the file:

```
IFile file = ...

IJavaElement element = JavaCore.create(file); 

if (element instanceof ICompilationUnit) {
  ICompilationUnit compUnit = (ICompilationUnit)element;

  ...
}
```

Other objects may be returned, for example `IClassFile` for a .class file.

Comment: So, using this approach apparently when I do ```compUnit.getSource()``` I get a ```JavaModelException```. Does it make sense? How can I fix it?

Comment: @LuisCruz Sorry but I don't know enough about JDT to say. Ask a new question so other people can attempt to answer.

Comment: Done -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100699/how-can-i-mimic-fully-compatible-icompilationunit-from-standalone-java-files