# How can I mimic fully compatible ICompilationUnit from standalone Java files?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am hacking an Eclipse Plugin that is working perfectly for Java files in Java projects. I want to make it work for Java files in any kind of project.

This plugin processes each Java file as a `ICompilationUnit`. However, in my approach I can only get an instance of `File`.

Upon suggestion in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066054/get-icompilationunit-ityperoot-from-standalone-java-file-for-eclipse-plugin), I am manually creating an `IJavaElement` from any Java file:

```
IJavaElement element = JavaCore.create(file);
```

This seems to work fine, except for some specific cases. E.g., when I try to get the source of the file I get the exception `JavaModelException`:

```
ICompilationUnit compUnit = (ICompilationUnit)element;
compUnit.getSource();
```

Exception message:

```
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [test does not exist]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.newJavaModelException(JavaElement.java:566)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.openAncestors(Openable.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:241)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.openAncestors(Openable.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:241)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.openAncestors(Openable.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.openAncestors(CompilationUnit.java:1176)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:241)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:579)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:316)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:302)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.getBuffer(Openable.java:285)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.getSource(CompilationUnit.java:903)
at org.autorefactor.refactoring.rules.RefactoringContext.getSource(RefactoringContext.java:126)
... 19 more
```

I'm afraid the same will happen with other methods. How can I have a fully working `ICompilationUnit`/`IJavaElement`?

Edit: I've figured that if the source file is open in the editor, I won't get this exception. Still, how to avoid it?

Comment: What does the JavaModelException say?

Comment: ```Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [test does not exist]```

Comment: I've just updated my question with a more verbose output of the exception @greg-449

Comment: That exception appears to be saying something doesn't exist. From the look of this you are doing this during refactoring - are you sure the files, folders and projects actually exist at the point you are doing this (what is 'test'?)

Comment: To be honest I can't figure where is it getting 'test'. Anyway I'd like the java file to be refactored with out requiring to have a project as context. The refactoring itself does not seem to require a whole project. Besides, methods like ```org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.openAncestors``` seem to be trying to go up to to the tree root and are getting me these weird failures :(

Comment: Ok @greg-449 I think I got it -- 'test' is the name of my generic project. It is not a java project, though, and perhaps that's why it fails. However, how to make it project agnostic??